# Как запихнуть ссылку в буфер обмена при нажатии "Скопировать" на сайте?

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Словом, заголовок и есть вопрос.
Есть php переменная $url, как при клике на ссылку сохранить это значение в буфер обмена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ZeroClipboard](http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/ui/zeroclipboard.html).